# How to set Library directory for "Object" target

Tags: cmake

I would need to specify a *library directory* property for OBJECT target like this:

```
add_library( ObjTargetName OBJECT "main.cpp" )
set_target_properties( ObjTargetName PROPERTIES STATIC_LIBRARY_FLAGS "/DEF")
```

It is an OBJECT target, but there is **/DEF** flag. And because it is OBJECT target type and not SHARED so **link_directories** does not work for this case. Is there a way how to specify it? I am using cmake 3.13 and VC2017.
Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Did you try setting the `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` or the `ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` property in your `set_target_properties` command? Did it produce an error? Was it ignored?

Comment: LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY and ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY properties are ignored. There is no error, they are simply ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set_target_properties( ObjTargetName PROPERTIES STATIC_LIBRARY_OPTIONS "/DEF;/OUT:${IMPLIB_FILE_PATH}")
```